# How to run .Net 6 API with NGINX reverse proxy

Tags: asp.net-core, nginx, asp.net-web-api, nginx-reverse-proxy

I try to run a .Net 6 API with NGINX on a Raspberry PI 3B, according to this documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-6.0

I configured my API as described in the article, the API is reachable under localhost.

I installed NGINX, the landing page is only locally reachable under http://192.168.178.51/index.nginx-debian.html not from other clients.

Also http://192.168.178.51/swagger does not work, nether locally or from clients.

One question for me is, where to locate the ForwardHeadersOptions?

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});

app.UseAuthentication();
```

The article says “*Invoke the UseForwardedHeaders method at the top of Startup.Configure before calling other middleware.*”

I have no Startup.Configure in my project. Does this description not fit for .Net 6?

This is my program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
}

app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

Is it correct?

This is my default NGINX file:

```
server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   test.abc *.test.abc;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

server {
    listen   80 default_server;
    # listen [::]:80 default_server deferred;
    return   444;
}
```

Whats wrong in my configuration?

BTW: No access from the internet possible, currently I’ll run it only in my local network.

I posted a minimal project here: https://github.com/Christoph1972/API_NGINX_Demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.

```
server {
    listen   80 default_server;
   
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Any doubts for this solution?

Next I’ll figure out how to create a server name for a private network, like test.abc.